# ASP.NET Core and Angular Deployment - page refresh gives 404 error

Tags: asp.net, angular, http-status-code-404, web-deployment, plesk

I am working on a project in Angular and ASP.NET Core hosted on Plesk. The project is working fine except the page refresh yields the 404 page not found error.  Whenever I hit refresh from the browser or reload the page, it gives the 404 error.

The structure of the files it's in the picture below.

[image]The content in web.config is:

[image]In the "wwwroot" folder I have the build from Angular, where I created a "web.config" file with the following content:

[image]Also in the "wwwroot" folder, I have the "index.html" file with the following content:

[image]Please guide me to solve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow ! Please don't show picture of code but prefer copy/paste and format them

Answer (score 1):

I ran in the same problem last night, but with a Vue application that uses ASP .net 6.0 in the backend.
The reason of the error is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057874/angular-11-error-404-when-opening-new-tab),   but I used a different solution to solve this problem.

My solution was adding a MapFallbackTocontroller controller in program.cs:

```
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");

await app.RunAsync();
```

and then creating said FallbackController.cs:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class FallbackController : Controller
{
   public IActionResult Index()
   {
      return PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "index.html"), "text/html");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Net 6 and angular spa application refresh 404 issue appears.Along with index html changes add below lines in program/startup.cs refreshing issue fixed .
[snippet mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser)

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>{
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me:

```cs
// Configure endpoints
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // your other endpoint mappings...
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding

```
 <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
```

instead of

```
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
```

Comment: Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

On .NET 7, in `Program.cs` this is already handled with this line of code.

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

But if your `index.html` is inside a subfolder within `wwwroot`, this is how to configure it.

```
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(app.Environment.WebRootPath, "MySubFolder"));
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html", new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = ""
});
```

If the `index.html` is in a folder (e.g.: ClientApp/dist) outside `wwwroot`, `fileProvider` should be created like this.

```
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp", "dist", "index.html"));
```